# I have been asked this in interview . Is LinkedHashSet or LinkedList faster?

Tags: performance, hashset

This was something asked to me in an interview. Among `LinkedList` and `LinkedHashSet` which is faster. What I understand is since `hashCode` and `equals` used along with `LinkedHashSet` then it will take time for `LinkedHashSet` to execute during a `put` operation. But what about the case where `hashCode` and `equals` are not used? Also is it right to compare the speed of `LinkedList` and `LinkedHashSet`. Because what I feel is the good design practice is to compare which interface we have to go `List` or `Set` and from there we have to decide which class we have to go for. Let me know your opinion on this.

Comment: Just because the developer hasn't implemented `hashCode` and `equals`, doesn't meant they don't exist. They will still be there, just not in an overriden state. So `LinkedHashSet` is still slower in that regard. Sometimes some developers, although wanting a unique list, might need the speed instead and will do manual checks elsewhere (E.g. before adding to the list), so there could be a possibility of using a `LinkedList`, in this case, instead of a `LinkedHashSet`, but it relies on the programmer controlling the data insert into such a list

Comment: This doesn't feel like a valid question, because a `LinkedHashSet` is a `Set` and a `LinkedList` is a `List`.  A `List` can have duplicate items, while a `Set` cannot, so you cannot just use a `LinkedHashSet` as a replacement for a `LinkedList`.  Comparing their performance therefore doesn't even make sense.

Comment: For a theoretical question, to confirm someone understands the difference, could you see it as a question @Claies? I supposed it should have been better worded as what is the difference between a `LinkedHashSet` and a `LinkedList`, but I feel they are just checking for the OP's understanding of the differences between the classes

Comment: @Draken I mostly mean that if it were asked as a question in an interview, it wouldn't seem fair.  Not necessarily that it's not valid to be asked about here, though even in that context, it seems more like a discussion than anything....

Comment: I was more talking about for the interview question @Claies. There is a possibility it was designed to trip someone up if they hadn't realised that there are major core underlying differences between the two classes, not just in possible speed of using the said classes.

Comment: LinkedHashSet is a "ordered set". In other terms, elements are referenced inside like a LinkedList but your object follows the constraints of a Set (unicity of elements inside. unicity determined by hashCode and equals). So, a linkedHashSet should be slower than a linkedList but this question is very stupid. The good question(s) should be : "do I need a Set or a List. And if I need a Set, should it be ordered or not"

Answer (score 1):

From [Jesper de Jong](https://coderanch.com/t/572764/java/Arraylist-LinkedList-LinkedHashSet) (in a context where ArrayList was also considered):

> About creation, it's just as the other two, there's no reason to assume anything about how fast creating a new LinkedHashSet is. Since LinkedHashSet uses a doubly-linked list to maintain the order of its elements, accessing an element by index will be just as inefficient as with LinkedList. Checking if an element exists in the set will be more efficient.
>
> Note that LinkedHashSet is a Set, which is a different thing than a List. A List can have duplicate elements, a Set cannot have duplicate elements. So you cannot just use LinkedHashSet as a replacement for ArrayList or LinkedList in any situation.